# XPath in PHP Removes HTML Tags

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I am using XPath in PHP to retrieve part of an HTML document. Assume that my HTML document looked like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="first">
            <a href="some_link_address.com">Hello</a>
            <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p>Some other text here</p>
            <img src="src/to/image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my PHP including the XPath call is:

```
$result_dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$node_to_keep = $xpath->query("//div[@id='first']");

foreach ($nodes_to_keep as $node) {

    $element = $result_dom->createElement('div', $node->nodeValue;);
    $result_dom ->appendChild($element);
}
```

I was expecting that the resulting dom will contain the following

```
<div>
    <a href="some_link_address.com">Hello</a>
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

However this is the resulting dom

```
<div>
    Hello
    Some text here
</div>
```

So my question is, how do I set the resulting dom to contain the html tags. I do not want them removed

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nodeValue" of an element is the textual content of that element.  The text nodes in the document do not include the <a ...>, etc., just the text inside and between those elements.  So, this is all you get in the new element.

Instead of creating a node manually, import a deep copy of the result node and append that:

```
$importedNode = $result_dom->importNode($node, true);
$result_dom->appendChild($importedNode);
```