# XPath select and echo entire row including <tr> and <th>

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am parsing some table data using Xpath and need to echo the header row plus any rows that contain certain data. I can successfully select what I want but am not sure of the syntax to output the entire rows including the html tr and th tags.

Here is my code. I am not sure how to simplify the verbose output of the selected lines. I tried the commented out line but it strips the tags.

It is similar to this question: [XPath in PHP Removes HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448563/xpath-in-php-removes-html-tags?rq=1) but I do not understand the answer.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$rows = $xpath->query('//table//tr');  // extract rows from html
echo '<table>';
$first = true; 
foreach ($rows as $row) {  // process each row of results
    if ($first) {  // echo header row           
       echo '<tr><td>'.$td->item(0)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(1)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(2)->textContent.
            '</td><td>'.$td->item(3)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(4)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(5)->textContent.
            '</td><td>'.$td->item(6)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(7)->textContent.'</td></tr>';
       $first = false;
    }
    else {
    $td = $xpath->query('td', $row); 
        $firstnm = trim(strtok($td->item(1)->textContent," "));
        $mmyyyy = substr($td->item(3)->textContent,2,7);
        if ($firstnm == $firstname && $mmyyyy == $thismth)  
               echo '<tr><td>'.$td->item(0)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(1)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(2)->textContent.
                    '</td><td>'.$td->item(3)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(4)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(5)->textContent.
                    '</td><td>'.$td->item(6)->textContent.'</td><td>'.$td->item(7)->textContent.'</td></tr>';
// THIS STRIPS THE TAGS  echo $row->nodeValue;
        }

    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: could you also post the sample html markup so that we could see that you are parsing.

Comment: It is just a totally standard table with a table header and table rows with tr, td td td.. tr. I am simply looking for the Xpath statement that gives the whole row in text format retaining the tr and td's.

Comment: have you tried using [`DOMDocument::saveHTML($node)`](http://php.net/domdocument.savehtml) with the `$node` parameter?